# Animate by alternating different UIImages

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I have two different images, that are essentially just inverses of each other.  I would like to animate them back and forth to create a somewhat moving effect.  In the AppDelegate didFinishLaunching I have:

```
myImageWalk = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 568)];
    [self.myImageWalk setImage: [self loadingImage]];

    [window addSubview:myImageWalk];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:myImageWalk];
```

Then, also in the App Delegate, I have:

```
-(UIImage*)loadingImage
{
    NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                                nil];
    return [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:animationFrames duration:6.0f];
}
```

But, nothing happens, no image ever shows up.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, so apparently the issue was in how I was setting the UIImage for the UIImageView.  It needed to be     `myImageWalk.image = [self loadingImage];`   However, it just continues and never goes away.  How do I remove it from SuperView after the duration is over?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You mention creating a moving effect, but then you also want to have it be a one time thing? Can you edit your question to more clearly express your intent and what is not meeting your expectation right now?

Comment: [myImageWalk startAnimating] and for stopping [myImageWalk stopAnimating]???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code below you can try.
Note you don't need to repeat the series of imageNamed:, just set duration as needed for one loop.

```
myImageWalk = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 568)];
myImageWalk.image = [self loadingImage];
self.myImageWalk.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[window addSubview:myImageWalk];
[window bringSubviewToFront:myImageWalk];

//when you want the animation to start
[self animateImages];
//then later at some appropriate time:
[self stopAnimatingImages];

- (UIImage*)loadingImage {
    NSArray *animationFrames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"second.png"],
                            nil];
    return [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:animationFrames duration:6.0f];
}
- (void)animateImages {
    if (![self.myImageWalk isAnimating]) {
        [self.myImageWalk startAnimating];
    }
}
- (void)stopAnimatingImages {
    if ([self.myImageWalk isAnimating]) {
        [self.myImageWalk stopAnimating];
    }
}
```

Note: unless this is a test app or class assignment, you should move this logic from AppDelegate to ViewContoller, as it is best practice to minimize the work done during didFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but maybe try wrapping your code inside this block:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:6f animations:^{

    [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:animationFrames duration:6.0f]

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Callback after animation was completed
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}];
```